# Software to reduce size of a video file and calculate the output size

Tags: video, video-editing, media-converter

I need a software to reduce my video files (lower resolution, quality etc...) but it has to have the option to calculate the size (in MB for example) of the output file before starting the conversion process.

Something like what `Cyberlink Power Director` does in Windows OS.

Is there anything like that for `Linux` OS?

Thanks

Comment: Free or commercial, what OS?

Comment: I would suggest that the displayed final size would almost certainly be an estimate based on the initial size and details and the options selected rather than a calculation.

Comment: See the answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546345/how-to-calculate-ffmpeg-output-file-size